# Change contextmenu text based on list item

Tags: android, android-listview, contextmenu

Lets say I have a list of friends stored in a database and showed in a list in my activity. For this list, I have an context menu with "edit", "delete" and "bad friend/good friend".
The case is that I would like to change the text of the last item in the menu ("bad friend/good friend") based on a value in the database. (Toggle the text).

If the friend is a good friend, the context menu text should be "not good friend" and if the friend is a bad friend, the text should be "good friend". This means that a click on this item in the context menu toggles the friends from good to bad or bad to good.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the code where you prepare and open the context menu. And how you fetch the database items to an adapter and populates the list view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this approach.

Declare two activity fields:

```
private int listItemPressedPos;
private long listItemPressedId;
```

Declare an `onItemLongClick` event and use them to save position and id of listItem clicked

```
myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int pos, long id) {

        listItemPressedPos = pos;
        listItemPressedId = id;
        return false;
    }
});
```

In onCreateContextMenu method get the row from database by Id and change the menu accordingly.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.dispositivos_list_context, menu);

    //Change this part accordingly your needs
    if(tbDispositivos.isSelected(listItemPressedId)){//get value from database
        //Alter the menuItem
        menu.findItem(R.id.dispositivosContextItemDelete).setVisible(false);
    }
}
```